# FATAL EXCEPTION: GoogleApiHandler

Tags: android, ads, vungle-ads, applovin

In my project i'm using the monetization service(Vungle/AppLovin).
When I'm trying to load an ad, i get this exception

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GoogleApiHandler
>                          Process: kz.ikar, PID: 3673
>                          java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setChannelId(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder; in class Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder' appears in /data/app/kz.ikar-2oCl4DY4J8w7wP-jirbYvA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
>                              at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.zza(Unknown Source:225)
>                              at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.zza(Unknown Source:15)
>                              at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbm.zzc(Unknown Source:4)
>                              at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbo.onConnectionFailed(Unknown Source:104)
>                              at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbo.connect(Unknown Source:83)
>                              at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbo.zza(Unknown Source:47)
>                              at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbm.handleMessage(Unknown Source:283)
>                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)

In my project I have two fragments in one activity. The user gets an ad in the second one. If I load an ad from the activity, it works well. What can be the cause of this issue?

By the way both ad networks(Vungle and AppLovin) return this exception

Comment: Are you using the Support Library's v4 fragment?

Comment: @squeeish Yeap!

Comment: I don't know the solution, but here's a clue: `setChannelId`, which was added in API 26, isn't found.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I fixed it downgrading to firebase Google Play services 11.6.0

Comment: same problem here, where do you downgrade the Google Play service exactly?

Answer (score 0):

One reason you could be getting this error is if your `buildToolsVersion` in your app-level Gradle is less than 26. Either that or your v4 support is less than `26.0.0` seeing as `NotificationCompat.Builder` was added in API 26.