# App crash when call fetch() form firebase remote config

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I try to call fetch from remote config and I've got this error.

The dependencies that I use.

```
def google_play_version = "11.8.0"

compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$google_play_version"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$google_play_version"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:$google_play_version"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:$google_play_version"
```

And the error

```
05-24 16:49:33.175 8637-8713/com.eatigo.merchant.staging E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GoogleApiHandler
    Process: com.eatigo.merchant.staging, PID: 8637
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzz(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzaa; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa' appears in /data/app/your.package.staging-2/base.apk:classes15.dex)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzx.zzbd(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbhp.zzdc(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbhp.zzdd(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbhr.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbht.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzm.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzc.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbo.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbo.zzaiw(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbo.onConnected(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.onConnected(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzn.zzakr(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zze.zzw(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi.zzaks(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzh.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: I had got the same issue.. make sure that every package you have installed uses the same version of firebase libraries

Comment: update your gms: play version to the latest in gradle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FATAL EXCEPTION: GoogleApiHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48185978/fatal-exception-googleapihandler)

Comment: @jakirhussain you know downgrading to lower version is not recommended?

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575810/nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-zzb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just update my gms: play version to the latest in Gradle